# How can I optimize this recursive function which calls setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following function is using 100% of a CPU core on my computer. Is there a way I could rewrite it to be non-recursive? Would that fix it or is it because my CPU sucks? Are others seeing the same performance problems on their computer?

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function timeMsg(n,max,delay)
        {
            writeToLog(n + "th: &#" + n,n);
            var temp = n + 1;
            if(n < max){
                var t=setTimeout("timeMsg(" + temp + "," + max + "," + delay + ")",delay);
            }

        }
        function writeToLog(text,n){
            $("#log").html($("#log").html() + text + "<br/>");
            //autoscrolling: doesn't work...'

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds" onClick="timeMsg(0,100000,100)" />
    </form>

    <div id="log"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeatedly calling setTimeout with slightly-different values, you could setup a global variable to track the current iteration, and use one call to setInterval() instead.  setInterval is like setTimeout, except it will keep running indefinitely - you don't have to call it over and over again.  That might help, a bit.

Answer (score 1):

That should not be using 100% CPU. (But the actual performance is dependent on the size of your document.) However, one obvious improvement is to get rid of the implicit `eval` in `setTimeout`:

```
function timeMsg(n, max, delay) {
    writeToLog(n + "th: &#" + n, n);
    var temp = n + 1;
    if(n < max) {
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
            timeMsg(temp, max, delay);
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

You should also use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in place of the double-html (anti-)pattern you're currently employing:

```
function writeToLog(text,n){
    $("#log").append(text + "<br/>");
}
```

There's no need to search for `#log` twice (reading its `html` both times).

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` to start and `clearInterval()` when you reach your max.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/PwASf/

Script:

```js
var timer;

function startMsg( n, max, delay ) {

    timer = window.setInterval( function() {
        timeMsg( n++, max );
    }, delay );;

};

function timeMsg( temp, max ) {

    writeToLog(temp + "th: &#" + temp, temp);

    if( temp == max ){
        window.clearInterval( timer );
    }

}

function writeToLog(text,n){
    $(' #log' ).append( text + '<br/>' );
}

startMsg( 1, 10, 1000 );
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, even as written, it doesn't use 100% CPU for me.

First thing you should do is change your writeToLog function.  It is must faster to append an HTML block than to 1) read the existing HTML, 2) add the text+BR, 3) write the whole thing back in.

```
function writeToLog(text,n){
       $("#log").append(text + "<br/>");
        //autoscrolling: doesn't work...'

}
```

Other than that, if you want to not block other JS from running, then you need to use the setTimeout/setInterval method of implementing this loop.  Otherwise a regular for loop is faster.